# componentDidMount does not fire on second time then I pass second router paramater value

Tags: reactjs

I am handling react component by using router parameter,and also I have set router paramater value in state using **componentDidMount** event life cycle.It works fine as per my requirement,but "componentDidMount" does not fire on second time when I pass second router paramater value.Please check my below code and advise how to do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ConfigItem from '../../Config';
import axios from 'axios';
class ZohoDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {url: ''};

    }
    componentDidMount() {


        console.log('mount');
        axios.get(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'Menus/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.data[0].URL);
            this.setState({url:res.data.data[0].URL});
        }) 
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render');
        return (

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src={this.state.url} allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>



        );
    }
}

export default ZohoDashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Router params in url are supposed to trigger a prop change and hence do not remount the component. Instead they trigger a re-render, you can make use of `componentDidUpdate` to trigger an API when route param changes

```js
class ZohoDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {url: ''};

    }
    componentDidMount() {


        console.log('mount');
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = () => {
      axios.get(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'Menus/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.data[0].URL);
            this.setState({url:res.data.data[0].URL});
        }) 
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
            this.fetchData()
        }
    }
    render() {
        console.log('render');
        return (

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src={this.state.url} allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>



        );
    }
}
```